# How to initialise static instance of a class without copy constructor>

Tags: c++, qt, static, initialization, c++14

I have class without copy constructor or assignment operator.  I need to create and initialize a instance of that class. How do I do that?

Code with the problem (example):

```
class Q
{
    int w;
    public:
    Q():w(19){};
    Q(const Q&) = delete;
    Q& operator = (const Q&) = delete;

    static Q sQ;
};

Q Q::sQ = Q();
```

[On ideone](http://ideone.com/HzsA77)

Use case: I have a class that is derived from `QObject` and so has its assignment operator and copy constructor deleted. There should be a static instance of the class available, how can that be achieved?

Comment: Doesn't simple `Q Q::sQ;` work for you?

Comment: There is a proposal to make copy elision guaranteed, so code like this would compile even with deleted copy and move constructors.  http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0135r0.html

Comment: It's like all of your Q's are pregnant at the same time with the same baby Q; curious, pregnant itself in an infinite cycle. Well, adopting the definition Q Q::sQ; proposed by HolyBlackCat, with a member function void f() { std::cout << "smoke and mirrors\n";  }  You can do now
 Q q;
 q.sQ.sQ.sQ.sQ.sQ.sQ.sQ.sQ.sQ.sQ.sQ.sQ.sQ.f();

Comment: @Loreto that's some image...

Comment: @Srv19 You have got a paradox machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [uniform initialization syntax](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#uniform-init) and construct the class with a empty set of curly braces

```
Q Q::sQ{};
```

or you can even drops the curly braces like:

```
Q Q::sQ;
```

Both will default construct `sQ`.

Comment: std::mutex is a good example, where both copy constructor and assignment operator are =delete;  If your class Yourcalss { static mutex mtx; }; you can initialize a static mutex Yourcalss::mtx{}